# Since Google now requires every app must have a privacy policy, do apps need to have one even if no data is collected?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-games, developer-console

##### [Google recently published a change inside of the google developer console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9934569?ref_topic=9877065&hl=en) ...

...stating that now *every app must have a privacy policy.*

What does this new mandatory change mean for developers? Do we have to aquire **formal legal documents from lawyers** or is a simple write up such as "xyz/nothing is being collected" enough ?

Secondly what if you create an app that does not collect any data at all, is a privacy policy still necessary ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Btw just as an update, that question is completely off topic and did not help me in any way, but of course SF as always pretending to be a real office, agrees silentely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you *must* have a Privacy Policy, even if all it says is:

> FizzBuzz(TM) does not collect any data.

You do not generally need a lawyer (says the non-laywer) to write a Privacy Policy, as long as your PP is *accurate* about what it collects (or doesn't collect). If your PP is inaccurate Google will blacklist your app, at least until you can convince a living Google employee that your PP has been sufficiently updated.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I had to do some digging myself back when I wrote this question, it still angers me that the question got thrown into the bin of "off-topic", deleted and unanswerable questions, even though this is a legitimate, not asked, extremely important question that literally affects every android developer! But then again, almost every app breaks either PP or Google Guideline. The entire playstore is a giant scam&spam pool where the honest-by-the-book (here guideline) dev gets squashed in the ocean of apps that dont follow the guidelines and steal screen realestate.